# How to get server type with dmidecode?

Tags: linux, redhat

For example I have HP ProLiant DL380 G6.

How can I get this information with command dmidecode? or I have to use another command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dmidecode -s  system-product-name
```

Answer (score 1):

On my ProLiant DL180 G5 this works.

```
# dmidecode -t 1|grep -E '(Product Name|Manufacturer)'
Manufacturer: HP
Product Name: ProLiant DL180 G5
#
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no "works-every-time" route to doing this, you basically have to just build up a picture through looking at the responses to the various dmidecode options but on servers with out-of-band management (such as HP's iLO) doing a 'dmidecode -t baseboard' should display at least something of interest.

Of course if you KNOW it's a HP server you can always install their PSP driver set which will let you get a lot more information than you can purely by using dmidecode.

Answer (score 0):

if you run 

`dmidecode | less`

and look for "System Information" that should give you what you want.

you should not need any other command but I found myself sometimes using lshw.

Answer (score 0):

See: 
[HP ProLiant DL360 G6 reporting missing fan](https://serverfault.com/questions/386556/hp-proliant-dl360-g6-reporting-missing-fan/386564#386564)

I use something like the following, rolled into a script:

```
dmidecode -t 1 | egrep '(Manufacturer|Product|Serial)'; dmidecode -t processor| egrep '(Socket|Version)'
```

The output is:

```
[root@LAS ~]# dmidecode -t 1 | egrep '(Manufacturer|Product|Serial)'; dmidecode -t 0 | egrep '(Version|Release)'; dmidecode  -t processor| egrep '(Socket|Version)'
        Manufacturer: HP
        Product Name: ProLiant DL380 G6
        Serial Number: 2UXxxxx6KT      
        Version: P62
        Release Date: 05/05/2011
        Socket Designation: Proc 1
        Version: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5570 @ 2.93GHz            
        Upgrade: Socket LGA1366
        Socket Designation: Proc 2
        Version: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5570 @ 2.93GHz            
        Upgrade: Socket LGA1366
```